# A relative Abel-Jacobi map on cycle classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, algebraic-cycles

I have a question about relativizing a classical cohomological construction that I think should be easy for someone well versed in such manipulations.

**Background:**

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb Q$ and $Z \subset X$ is a cycle of pure codimension $d$. In this case, one can define a cycle class $[Z] \in H^{2d}_{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb Q_\ell(-d))$ in an appropriate etale cohomology group. When this cycle class is $0$, i.e., $Z$ is homologically trivial, one can nevertheless define an element in the group cohomology $H^1(G_{\mathbb Q}, H_{et}^{2d-1}(\overline{X},\mathbb Q_\ell(-d)))$ using something I have heard referred to as the Abel-Jacobi map.

Roughly, I think of this in the following way. Suppose $[Z] = d\eta$ for some degree $2d-1$  element $\eta$ in a complex of $\ell$-adic sheaves representing etale cohomology. Then, for any $g$ a Galois automorphism, we can define a cycle $g(\eta)-\eta$ which is killed by the differential because $Z$ is defined over $\mathbb Q$. This is the require element in the group cohomology.

**Question:**

Now, suppose we move to a relative setting where $\pi: X \to S$ is a smooth proper morphism over $\mathbb Q$, and $Z \subset X$ is smooth relative to $S$ and of codimension $d$ in $X$ (fibrewise). In this case, I believe one can define a cycle class element $[Z] \in R^{2d}\pi_*(\mathbb Q_\ell)$, but do not know a reference for it. Let us suppose this is possible, and moreover, let us suppose that this cycle class element is $0$ as before. In this case, I believe that the following is true but do not know how to prove it:

First, we factor $Z \to S$ as $Z \to S' \to S$ where $Z \to S'$ has connected fibers and $S' \to S$ is etale. Let $H = \pi_(\overline{S'})$ be the corresponding geometric monodromy group and for simiplicity, suppose that $H$ is normal in $\pi_1(S)$ so that we can define $\Gamma = \pi_1(S)/H$.

**Claim:** Then, it should be possible to define the image of $[Z]$ through an Abel-Jacobi like map in the group cohomology as $AJ(Z) = H^1(\Gamma,R^{2d-1}\pi_*(\mathbb Q_\ell)^{H})$ where the coefficients are the $H$-invariants. Moreover, this should satisfy the compatibility that for any rational point $s \in S(\mathbb Q)$, the pullback of $AJ(Z)$ over $s$ should match the usual AJ map in the absolute setting.

I would be very happy to hear the sketch of an argument proving the above claim, or even better a reference. If the above is not strictly true, I would also be happy to hear of close modifications that are true.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the sentence ' for any rational point s in S(Q), the pullback of AJ(Z) over s should match the usual AJ map in the absolute setting'. How it the pullback of an element of $H^1(\Gamma, R^{2d-1}\pi_*(\mathbb{Q}_l)^H)$ naturally an element of $H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}}, H^{2d-1}(\bar{X},\mathbb{Q}_l))$? Also what do you mean by $Z\rightarrow S'$ having connected fibres? Each closed subscheme in the support of $Z$ has connected fibres?

Comment: You could try F. Charles “On the zero locus of normal functions and the étale Abel-Jacobi map”, and M. Green, P. Griffiths, K. Paranjape, “Cycles over fields of transcendence degree one”, and the references contained therein.

Comment: @Jef,sorry I was implicitly assuming that Z is connected, but yes I mean that each closed subscheme has connected fibers.

Comment: @Jef as for the first question, a version of cohomology and base change will give you a map from (the restriction of the higher pushforward to s) to (the higher cohomology group). Moreover, by assumption the absolute galois group includes into $\Gamma$ using the section and you can use these two compatibilities to compare the two AJ images. It's possible I got this slightly wrong, but some version of such a comparison should exist.